# restore access to win xp

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I am very new to Linux and wanted to try it to see if the package could meet my needs.  I installed Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Win XP after manually altering the partition table in the ubuntu install process.  All worked well with dual boot.  I then discovered that there were a couple of key powerpoint functions that I use regularly and could not replicate them in impress.  I continued using Win xp but began to have problems because of lack of hard drive space.  I used the ubuntu install disk to delete the ubuntu partitions and return the drive to completely NTFS.  Now a regular boot gives me GRUB and goes nowhere, no prompts, no option to load windows, nothing.  I now from looking at the drive from ubuntu run from the DVD that all the windows files are there but I cannot get windows running.  I even tried re installing Ubuntu 12.04 and I know it is there because a further attempt to re-install announced that it was there but I still get GRUB missing or something.  What now?  And keep it simple, I know windows pretty well but not linux

Comment: Your question seems to be about Windows rather than Ubuntu, but I'll point you in the right direction.

Comment: You can try Boot Repair https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 1):

What I can understand from your question is that, when you resized your hardrive partitions, it shifted everything a little (likely it shifted to the right if anything). Now the bootloader (loads the system) is located at bytes 0-512 and only those bytes, it it moved over, even a little, the OS won't boot (learn more about bootloaders if you decide to pick up OS Dev).

Backup data on HDD just in case something decides to go wrong!

### Easier Way (try this FIRST):

- Boot using the Windows Installation Disk (insert, restart computer, and press the key it tells you to press in order to access boot menu before Windows Logo shows up) and select the Disk.
- Select the option to repair your computer
- Select Startup Repair (it may be inside System Recovery or similar)

---

### Easy Way (aka Risky Way or Uber-1337 Way):

This will only work if my prediction about shifted partitions is correct.
To check (and possibly fix it), replace [TEXT] with appropriate data:

- Boot Ubuntu as Live

  If You Don't have GParted installed, create a [GParted](http://gparted.org/download.php) Bootable drive:

  - Open up the Terminal
  - `cd` to the directory where the GParted iso is downloaded
  - USB drive to use should be mounted as `/dev/sdb`, but to make sure type `df -aTh`, it will show a list of mounted drives, USB should be mounted on `/media/[USER_NAME]/[USB_LABEL]`
  - !WARNING - NEXT STEPS MAY LEAVE HARD DRIVE FUBAR'D, FOLLOW DIRECTIONS!
  - Type `sudo dd status=noxfer conv=notrunc if=[GPARTED_ISO] of=[DEVICE(/dev/sdb)]` to write iso to drive, it WILL take a minute (possibly 15) so if you did it right there's no data lost :)
  - Restart computer and boot GParted
- Unmount drive to "play" with
- Check for and delete any unused partitions
- Expand the Windows Partition to fill entire (unused space of) drive, makes sure that there are ZERO (0) bytes before the start of the partition
- If needed, move the partition all the way to the left (fairly long process as it goes through every byte of the partition little by little)

Good luck, and I hope you get it working!

Comment: I just found this today, a more friendly version of `df -aTh` is using the command `lsblk`. The formatting is simpler and easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer to your windows related question [here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ht/repairmbr.htm)